# Background Image in CSS Class inside to <div>

Tags: html, css, class, background, stylesheet

I am new at web design and I have a question to ask. I can not see background image in . Here is my code. What am I doing wrong? I am sure that image is in the right location and I linked style.css to my html code.

PHP:

```
<div style="main_div">
<div style="banner">


</div><!--banner end-->
</div><!--main end-->
```

CSS:

```
.main_div{width: 1000px; margin: auto;}

.banner{
width:100%; 
height:100%;
background-image: url(../img/bannerimg.png); 
margin-top:50px;}
```

I also have reset code of Eric Meyer in CSS code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `main_div` needs a `height` value. There's not content within your divs to raise the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the `style` to `class` and it should work. your problem is that you are working with the wrong keyword.

- `class` is to identify elements
- `id` is to identify a unique element
- `style` is to write `CSS` in the element

Answer (score 0):

Give the `main_div` class a height and change the 'style' attribute to 'class' instead.

```
.main_div {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can also set **background-repeat: no-repeat;** so that the image displays only once.

```
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="banner">

  </div><!--banner end-->
</div><!--main end-->

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/bannerimg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```